# Distance between user's location and a location entered by user

Tags: android, location, distance

I want to find the distance between the location of the user and a place he enters. The entered location will be an address. Using location class I can find the coordinates of the user's location but how can I find those of the entered location. Couldn't find that in Google Maps API as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the location from an address like this:

```
public GeoPoint getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress) {
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress,5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        GeoPoint p1 = new GeoPoint((int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6),
                          (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        return p1;
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return null;
}
```

And for the distance use [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29).